# Connect from docker container to a host port

Tags: docker

I have a server on the host which is listening to some port (let it be 8080). Also, I have docker container that has to connect to the port host port.

What is the way to do this?

I've tried to listen on `0.0.0.0:8080` on the host machine and connect to the address from container, but there is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to which address you were trying to connect from the container? Try using host's COMPUTERNAME as target. Localhost won't do, since from container perspective, localhost is the container, not the "host"

Comment: I tried to use the `0.0.0.0`. Can I use anybody certain address for this? It's great to have similar address on any machine.

Comment: I don't think that there is such "universal" address. We used passing as an environment variable windows env `%computername%` or `hostname` on linux to provide container the "host" dns name under which it should look for particular service. In production setup, you will use either a static IP or the server name anyway.